# Simple way to generate a sequence where the 1st number is $x_1$, the tenth number is $x_{10}>x_1$ and the 20th number is above some order of magnitude

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponentiation

I'm a bit stumped at the moment.

I'm trying to generate a sequence where the first number is 1.9, the tenth is 3, and the 20th is between $10^{5-6}$ .  There should be a function $f(x_1) = 1.9$, $f(x_{10}) = 3$, and $f(x_{20}) >10000$.  I've been thinking an exponential function, but maybe not.  Ideally it'd be a function that doesn't have any discontinuities.  The $x's$ should be equally spaced.

So:
$x_1^n = 1.9$, $x_{10}^n = 3$, $x_{10}-x_1 = d$, $x_{20}>10^5$, and $x_{20}<10^6$

Intuitively, there should be a whole set of $d$'s and $n$'s that would work.

I'm guessing that $d$ and $n$ would be uniquely identified if I specified $x_{20}$, but I can't show this at the moment.

Perhaps the solution is obvious and I'm just momentarily blind to it.  Help appreciated.

Edit:  I should mention that, when I simulate, I end up needing exponents $n$ that are larger than machine precision if I stick with an exponential function and specify $x_{20} = 10000^{1/n}$.  So an exponential seems not be the way to go.

Comment: When you say "the $x'$s should be equally spaced," what exactly do you mean?

Comment: x2-x1 = x3-x2, etc

Comment: Such a sequence is called an arithmetic progression. There is exactly one such sequence satisfying $x_1=1.9$ and $x_{10}=3,$ but this sequence does not satisfy your condition for $x_{20}.$

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you want something like $x(n)=a+be^{cn}$ and solve for the coefficients after substituting your desired values.

Seeing your condition for the values to be equally spaced, then what you ask cannot be done. Equally spaced means $x(n)=a+bx$, and you have three restrictions and only two parameters.